# Building a continuous relationship curve between cutoff and percentages

Tags: r

I have raw data where I want to see what kind of cutoff level results in what percentage of observations above the cutoff level. Here is the simulation:

```
data<-rnorm(100,50,30)
prop.table(table(data>10))
prop.table(table(data>20))
prop.table(table(data>30))
prop.table(table(data>40))
prop.table(table(data>50))
prop.table(table(data>60))
prop.table(table(data>70))
prop.table(table(data>80))
prop.table(table(data>90))
```

Here is the output:

```
FALSE  TRUE 
  0.1   0.9 

FALSE  TRUE 
 0.16  0.84 

FALSE  TRUE 
 0.29  0.71 

FALSE  TRUE 
 0.36  0.64 

FALSE  TRUE 
 0.51  0.49 

FALSE  TRUE 
 0.61  0.39 

FALSE  TRUE 
 0.75  0.25 

FALSE  TRUE 
 0.86  0.14 

FALSE  TRUE 
 0.91  0.09
```

But it is a crude and inefficient way as you would agree. Instread of calculating respective percentage for each cutoff value endlessly, I wanted to build a plot that represents that relationship where X axis would represent the range of the all possible cutoff levels, and Y axis representing percentages from 0 to 100. Something similar to this:

[image]

Please ignore the axis labels etc of the plot, this is only to provide a general example. Any suggestions?

Comment: `plot(cumsum(table(cut(data, c(-Inf, seq(10, 90, by=10))))/100))`, you can change the `breaks` argument for different cuts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You write:

> I have raw data where I want to see what kind of cutoff level results
>   in what percentage of observations above the cutoff level.

Taking what you write literally, then you want the proportion of observations above the cutoff. Say the cutoff is `X`. The empirical CDF gives you the value `P(x <= X)`, i.e. the proportion below the cutoff. If you want the value corresponding to  `P(x > X)`, you can use the equality `P(x > X) = 1-P(x <= X)`.

For instance:

```
data<-rnorm(100,50,30)            # your data
dat <- data.frame(x = sort(data)) # into sorted dataframe
dat$ecdf <- ecdf(data)(dat$x)     # get cdf values for each x value
dat$above <- with(dat, 1-ecdf)    # get values above

plot(dat$x, dat$above)
```

Having said all this, you are presenting the ECDF of a Gaussian distribution after all, which may indicate that you are looking for the ECDF instead. In this case, as already outlined in the Vincent's answers, you can just plot the corresponding values of `ecdf` instead of `above`. Here an example where I plot both.

To address your comment, I print one with a `smooth` line, using `geom_smooth` instead of `geom_line`.

```
library(ggplot2); library(scales) 
ggplot(dat, aes(x=x)) +   
geom_line(aes(y=ecdf), col="red" ) +      # P(x<=X) in red
geom_smooth(aes(y=above), col="blue") +   # Smooth version of P(x > X) 
labs(y="Proportion", x="Variate") +   
scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)
```

If you prefer the smoothed line to be printed without surrounding error intervals, you can add the option `se=F`. See `?geom_smooth`-

[image]

To achieve something similar with base plot, you can use

```
 plot(dat$x, dat$above, type="n")
 lines(loess.smooth(dat$x, dat$above, span=1/6))
```

though you may have to play around with the span parameter. This will give the following image:

[image]

Comment: I need this for lot of different data where gaussian distirbution cannot be assumed, so the first approach is what I need. If  I add `type="l"` to the plot commant, I get almost exactly what I nead. "almost" because I wanted the curve to be a fitted smooth, like a spline. How would I do that?

Comment: The Gaussian distribution is not assumed in my code, so that concern does not apply to the code above. If you want to have it plotted with a smoothed line, exchange `geom_line` with `geom_smooth`. I have adjusted the code accordingly to show you how to do it.

Comment: this is it, any way this csn be done in base graphics?

Comment: I am not using base that often anymore, but after a second of googling, I found that one possible `base` command is `loess.smooth()`. So, for instance, `plot(dat$x, dat$above, type="n"); 
lines(loess.smooth(dat$x, dat$above, span=1/6))` gives me reasonable results. You may have to play around with the `span`.

Answer (score 6):

I believe you are looking for the `ecdf()` function to create an empirical cumulative distribution function.

```
data<-rnorm(1000,50,30)
a = ecdf(data)
plot(a)
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Vmiu.png)

Comment: not quite: In the curve that I need,  for x value of 100, the y would be 0.048 `prop.table(table(data>100))`

Comment: @Oposum `plot(1 -a (seq(-50, 150, by = 0.1)), type = "l")`?